# View is not redrawn after updating QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, database, qt, mvvm, qtsql

There is a sub-class of QSqlTableModel.

```
class TaskManager : public QSqlTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit TaskManager(QObject *parent = 0){}
    void initMode();      
    bool addTask(Task &task);
    ...
}
```

This is initModel()

```
void TaskManager::initModel()
{
    setTable(currenttasks);
    setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
    select();
}
```

And this is addTask method

```
bool TaskManager::addTask(Task &task)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO currenttasks (description, numbers, imageid) "
                  "VALUES (:descr, :numbers, :imageid)");

    query.bindValue(":descr",   task.description);
    query.bindValue(":numbers", task.numbers);
    query.bindValue(":imageid", task.imageid);
    bool res = query.exec();
    reset();
    return res;
}
```

Also there's a view on QML. But if i click on "ADD" button calling addTask() method i cannot see the results. The view isn't redrawn. Also there is a proxy [QMLifyProxyModel](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=QMLifyProxyModel) inherited from QAbstractProxyModel but i do not believe that this is the problem.
I can see the changes in DB when i restart the application. 
It seems that the model does not read datas after updating.

By the way i tried to emit layoutChanged() after my query, no results.
What do i need to do that i immediately get new records in the view ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I know this is an old question, but I will give an answer for any that might need it later.

As far as I can see from the code the QSqlQuery will only update the database and not the model.

I would use the capabilities of QSqlTableModel:

```
bool TaskManager::addTask(Task &task)
{
    QSqlRecord record = this->record();
    record.setValue("description", task.description);
    record.setValue("numbers", task.numbers);
    record.setValue("imageid", task.imageid);

    // -1 means append
    return insertRecord(-1, record);
}
```

As the [documentation says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqltablemodel.html#insertRecord):

> Inserts the record at position row. If row is negative, the record will be appended to the end. Calls insertRows() and setRecord() internally.
>   Returns true if the record could be inserted, otherwise false.
>   Changes are submitted immediately for OnFieldChange and OnRowChange. Failure does not leave a new row in the model.

This should do all the magic to update the database as well as the model.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation from [QMLifyProxyModel](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=QMLifyProxyModel) it says that it does not yet support the update of the model upon changes to the source model.
So, if you use the QMLifyProxyModel to transition from the QSqlTableModel to the QML ListView than probably this is the reason why you're view is not refreshed.